# How to access files downloaded from kaggle into a Colaboratory notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am having some difficulties with manipulating multiple files in a Colaboratory Notebook downloaded to the /content directory in my google drive. So far, I have successfully downloaded and extracted a kaggle dataset to a Colaboratory Notebook using the following code:

```
!kaggle datasets download -d iarunava/cell-images-for-detecting-malaria -p /content
!unzip \cell-images-for-detecting-malaria.zip
```

I was also able to use Pillow to import a single file from the dataset into my Colaboratory session (I obtained the filename from the output produced during the extraction):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('cell_images/Uninfected/C96P57ThinF_IMG_20150824_105445_cell_139.png')
```

How can I access multiple extracted files from /content without knowing their names in advance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After some further experimentation, I found that the python os module works similarly in Colab Notebooks as it does on an individual computer. For example, in a Colab Notebook the command

```
os.getcwd()
```

returns '/content' as an output.

Also, the command `os.listdir()` returns the names of all the files I downloaded and extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **glob**. `glob.glob(pattern)` will match all files that match the pattern. For example the code bellow will read all the `.png` files in the `image_dir`.

```
png = glob.glob(os.path.join(img_dir, '*.png'))
png = np.array(png)
```

`png` will contain a list of filenames.

In your case you can use:

```
png = glob.glob('cell_images/Uninfected/*.png')
png = np.array(png)
```